# A scenario for combining multiple rows in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with vaues like

```
MY_ID(NUMBER) COL_1(NUMBER) COL_2(NUMBER) COL_3(VARCHAR2)
11              1001          NULL          GT
11              NULL          1002          TG
11              NULL          1003          TG2

12              1004          NULL          GT
12              NULL          1006          TG
12              NULL          1005          TG2
```

My expected result is

```
MY_ID(NUMBER) COL_1(NUMBER) COL_2(NUMBER) COL_3(VARCHAR2)
11                1001          1003           TG2
12                1004          1006           TG
```

I can use MAX for numbers, but how about the Varchar2?
How can I combine multiple rows like this?

Comment: You can use MAX for VARCHAR2 also, if that's what your problem requires. But does it? Same question applies to numbers, too - why MAX and not MIN? or AVG or SUM? Only you know - because only you know the BUSINESS problem behind all of this. For example for ID=12, why are you choosing TG and not TG2 or GT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MAX aggregate functions can be used for varchar too, see this example:

```
SELECT my_id, max( col_1 ), max( col_2 ), max( col_3 )
FROM Table1
GROUP BY my_id;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/406e8d7/6

```
| MY_ID | MAX(COL_1) | MAX(COL_2) | MAX(COL_3) |
|-------|------------|------------|------------|
|    11 |       1001 |       1003 |        TG2 |
|    12 |       1004 |       1006 |        TG2 |
```

---

However, in your question is stated that for the record `12` must be returned value `TG` instead `TG2`. I'm guessing that you want to return not the maximum column value of `COL_3`, but the value from the record for which the maximum value from column `COL2` exists. In such a case you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT my_id, max( col_1 ), max( col_2 ), 
      max( col_3 ) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY col_2 NULLS FIRST)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY my_id;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/406e8d7/6

```
| MY_ID | MAX(COL_1) | MAX(COL_2) | MAX(COL_3)KEEP(DENSE_RANKLASTORDERBYCOL_2NULLSFIRST) |
|-------|------------|------------|------------------------------------------------------|
|    11 |       1001 |       1003 |                                                  TG2 |
|    12 |       1004 |       1006 |                                                   TG |
```

Comment: I am trying too understand DENSE_RANK... Shall confirm the answer after that